# Mid risk inflation hedge for parents retirement with 10/15% of total?

Tags: retirement, inflation, leverage

My parents are very conservative and uneducated about money, and they’re keeping most of what will be their retirement (in 3/4 years) in CD. I convinced them this is detrimental due to inflation, but they only accept a suggestion to move about just 10/20% somewhere else.
What can I do to at least protect their total amount from inflation as much as possible without adding too much risk?
(If something goes bad, I’d assume financial responsibility and put from my own money back).

Comment: This needs a country tag.

Comment: What percentage is in retirement accounts (IRA, 401k, 403b, etc)?

Comment: @RonJohn Ron, I am in the US, parents are not but they can access the US market through me. The inflation rate there is estimated to be 4-6%. They have no access to tax advantaged accounts.

Comment: "parents are not but they can access the US market through me".  Does this mean that their money is in your name?

Comment: @RonJohn no, but I could open them an international account here and help them transfer that share.

Comment: @RonJohn ok, just removed it

Comment: @RonJohn there is no active tag for their country, which is in South America

Comment: Tell me the country, and I'll try and add a tag.

Comment: @RonJohn they’re in Chile. Thank you!

Comment: What are Chilean "CDs" paying, and why aren't their banks safe?

Comment: @RonJohn they get less than a 0.7% rate. Banks are not unsafe but not at the same level of US banks either. Inflation is my main concern as it’s always been in South America and now more given the now relaxed monetary policies.

Answer (score 4):

The question you should be asking is do your parents have enough so that their savings will last their lifetime despite inflation?  If yes, leave well enough alone.

It troubles me that you're going to bear the risk if their 10/20% investment amount  goes south and you'll  reimburse them.  Use your own money if you have that amount available to invest.

The bottom line is that risk and reward go hand in  hand and if you want reward, you have to take on risk.  Asking anonymous strangers on the internet for such advice isn't a great idea.  Not that I'm enamored with financial advisers but sitting down with one of them would be a better idea.

Comment: I am not saying no risk can be taken. The thing is inflation may eat a good % of the total, and they may adjust to that but they would compromise life quality without need. I have no problem risking 10% of that myself if in the end it may be I would end helping them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that -- at the moment -- any investment in the US which returns 4+% is going to involve risk (**especially** if they're going to need it in just 3-4 years).

Given that, high quality "junk" bond funds like VWEAX or HYG will tread water against 4-5% inflation.  (Just remember the risk of price collapse if **US** interest rates start to rise, and that "high quality" junk bonds are still higher risk than corporate and US government bonds.)

Comment: I understood that retirement *starts* in 3-4 years but the investment horizon would be much longer than that. They don't liquidate all investments on day 1.

Comment: @nanoman that's what paragraph 2 is for.

Comment: I don't entirely get the risk of price collapse. That's only on the remaining bond duration, and here we have a target date. It is possible to buy bonds which you plan to hold to maturity, at which time their price will have 0 dependency on US interest rates. You still have the insolvency risk, though.

Comment: @MSalters as you well know, bond and bond fund prices are inversely related to interest rates; if US rates start to rise, bond prices will fall (and junk bonds more than investment-grade bonds.   As far as buying individual bonds... that requires a (relatively) *lot* of money, since they are traded in units of 100-200 (thus each trade is $10K-$20K, and you'd need a lot more than that to protect against insolvency risk).

Comment: @RonJohn: ... which is why target maturity date ETF's exist. You simply buy a 2025 target maturity ETF, e.g. "iShares iBonds 2025". Since you're not planning on selling before 2025, the price risk between now and 2025 is not zero, but irrelevant. As noted, you probably don't want all the money on day one, so you also buy a few ETF's with a maturity date further away.

Comment: That’s a potential option. Still not an hedge but a way to preserve that share, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you can open an international account for them, why not use CDs in a US bank? This would hedge against Chilean inflation completely, though the US interest rates are uninspiring.

This is a variation on the South American tradition of holding savings in cash US dollars. There are plenty of South American-owned bank accounts in Miami, in US dollars.

Comment: Please expand on the reasoning why this is so.

Comment: @RonJohn: That seems pretty trivial? Inflation generally varies between currencies. Chilean inflation is pretty independent of US inflation.

Comment: It’s really not so independent. US imports have a significant weight in the local economy. That wouldn’t really be a solution per se.